# pg_partman with PostgreSQL native (declarative) partitioning

Tags: postgresql, database-partitioning, pg-partman

This question is on the relative merits of using [pg_partman](https://github.com/pgpartman/pg_partman) with PostgreSQL 12 when relying on its native or declarative partitioning mechanism where things are a lot simplified compared to the older (and more advanced) explicit table inheritance based mechanism.

I understood the advantage of using pg_partman previously (before pg introduced native mechanism & improved it in 11 & 12 versions) & still see the advantage when it comes to use cases that require the flexibility and features of explicit table inheritance based partitioning.

But when it comes to cases where the use of declarative partitioning is sufficient, i am trying to understand what is the advantage of introducing it in the stack versus creating & maintaining the partitions directly.

Thanks